# ERROR 1064 in mysql, can anybody check what is the error?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, database-cursor

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_user(in uname varchar(20),in gender varchar(20),in email varchar(20),in phone varchar(20),in pword varchar(20),in city varchar(20)) 
BEGIN
DECLARE finished integer default 0;
Declare cnt integer default 0;
declare id integer;
DECLARE  c_cur cursor for select user_id from user;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLE FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
    open c_cur;
        ins_user: loop
        fetch c_cur into id;

                IF finished = 1 THEN 
                LEAVE ins_user;
                end if; 


                cnt:=id;
                end loop ins_user;
        cnt:=cnt+1;
        insert into user
        values(cnt,uname,email,phone,city,pword,gender);
END;
```

Am getting the error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'HANDLE FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1; open c_cur; ins_user: loop fetch ' at line 7
i am not sure where its getting wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Set the Delimiter to something else, other than `;`, for eg: `$$`. This will allow the parser to treat the whole `create` statement as one.
- At the end, redefine the Delimiter back to `;`
- `user` is a [keyword in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-U). It is better to rename your table to something else, or use backticks around it.
- There is a typo; it should be `HANDLER` not `HANDLE`

Try:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insert_user $$

CREATE PROCEDURE insert_user(in uname varchar(20),
                             in gender varchar(20),
                             in email varchar(20),
                             in phone varchar(20),
                             in pword varchar(20),
                             in city varchar(20)) 
BEGIN
DECLARE finished INT DEFAULT 0;
Declare cnt INT DEFAULT 0;
declare id INT;
DECLARE c_cur CURSOR FOR select user_id from `user`;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
    open c_cur;
        ins_user: loop
        fetch c_cur into id;

                IF finished = 1 THEN 
                LEAVE ins_user;
                end if; 


                SET cnt:=id; -- set was missing here
                end loop ins_user;
        SET cnt:=cnt+1; -- set was missing here

        insert into `user`
        values(cnt,uname,email,phone,city,pword,gender);
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: @Niti please post the exact error message you are getting.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':=id;
                end loop ins_user;
        cnt:=cnt+1;
        insert i' at line 22

Comment: now am getting another error. Am very sorry.am new to mysql so am finding it difficult

Comment: @Niti when we assign value to a variable, MySQL requires usage of `set` keyword. Check the updated answer now